About Platform Selection on EVSE's
I want to make a product. I would appreciate it if you could share your opinion about which platform would be more suitable for this product.
The product is in the "EV Charger" category, which will be used for charging electric vehicles. This product will be an IoT device and Raspberry Pi will be used. If we briefly talk about the functions of the product:

It will connect to the server over the internet. It will exchange information with this server.
It will have a touch screen. The user will be able to perform transactions on this screen.
There will be a motherboard other than Raspberry Pi. Different modules on this motherboard will be triggered with the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi.

I need a system that will run on Ubuntu. I have to choose between Ubuntu Core, Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Web server. Since this system is connected to the internet and available to the user, it must be secure.
I would be glad if you help. Enjoy your work.

You are specifically asking for off-topic opinions; this is a Q&A or Question and Answer site, where you provide your specific problem, and varies answers can provide solutions. Questions seeking opinions are best dealt with on forums (this isn't a forum) with https://ubuntuforums.org/ the address of Ubuntu Forums.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask where I see "no actual problem to be solved"
